# How in Bash script receive Tuesday before last Tuesday?

Tags: bash, date

I know that last Tuesday:

```
 date --date="2 Tuesday"
```

But if I need to get Tuesday before Tuesday ? -2 doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date --date='Tuesday - 2 weeks'
```

Comment: @gustavotkg: You probably wanted to comment on the other answer?

Comment: Nops. Today is Tuesday (November 8th) and this command returns me `Tue Oct 25 00:00:00` which is 14 days ago...

Comment: @gustavotkg: Yes. And it should work for other days, too. Or not?

Comment: Well, @choroba, it gets the next Tuesday and then subtract 2 weeks. If last Tuesday is needed, use `--date="Last Tuesday - 2 weeks"`

Comment: @gustavotkg: I get the same output. 
`for day in monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday ; do date --date="$day -2 weeks" ; date --date="last $day - 1 week" ; done`

Comment: Hmm... I also get it now. Maybe I tested something else, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If it's tuesday it is

```
date --date='Today - 2 weeks'
```